# optim() function error in parameter estimation

Tags: r

The following code is to find the 3 parameters of the generalized beta distribution.

```
beta1 = function(a,b,t) { beta(a+(1/t),b) }
beta2 = function(a,b,t) { beta(a+(2/t),b) }

geb11 = function(a,b,t) { beta2(a,b,t)/beta(a,b) }
geb12 = function(a,b,t) { (beta1(a,b,t)-beta2(a,b,t))/beta(a,b) }
geb22 = function(a,b,t) { 1 + (beta2(a,b,t)-2*beta1(a,b,t))/beta(a,b) }

gbetloglik = function(v) {
   a = v[1]; b = v[2]; t = v[3]
   loglik = n1*log(geb11(a,b,t)) + n3*log(geb12(a,b,t)) + n2*log(geb22(a,b,t))
   return(-loglik)
}

n1 = 127; n2 = 111; n3 = 262
abt = optim(c(5,5,1),gbetloglik,lower=c(0.01,0.01,0.1),method="L-BFGS-B")$par
```

Then it gives an error as follows with many warnings.

```
Error in optim(c(2, 8, 1), gbetloglik, lower = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.1), method = "L-BFGS-B") : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

The warning messages are

```
1: In beta(a + (2/t), b) : underflow occurred in 'beta'
2: In beta(a, b) : underflow occurred in 'beta'
3: In beta(a + (1/t), b) : underflow occurred in 'beta'
...
```

n1, n2 and n3 are generated by some random number generation scenarios, and (n1,n2,n3) decides whether an error occurs. (For some (n1,n2,n3) the error does not occur)

I don't understand what the reason of this error is and what "underflow in 'beta' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning message indicates there is underflow when computing beta.

Try this (where we have added the ## line):

```
gbetloglik = function(v) {
   a = v[1]; b = v[2]; t = v[3]
   if (beta(a, b) == 0) return(1e6) ##
   loglik = n1*log(geb11(a,b,t)) + n3*log(geb12(a,b,t)) + n2*log(geb22(a,b,t))
   return(-loglik)
}
```

Comment: It seems that the error occurs less frequently after adding that command, but it still occurs...

Comment: Then appropriately handle the other occurrences of beta as well.

Comment: Your suggestion solved the 'error.' But there are still 'underflow in beta' warnings.

Comment: Adding this line will suppress the warning messages coming from beta: `beta <- function(a, b) suppressWarnings(base::beta(a, b))`