# Parameter value when optim error occurred

Tags: r, optimization

Various errors may occur when we use optim() function in R.

When I want to replicate that error, I need to know the parameter value of the function when the error occurred.
Is there any way optim() outputs the current parameter value when any error occurs?

Please understand that I cannot provide reproducible example because it occurred with a large dataset, lengthy functions and several hours of computation time.

Comment: what about adding `trace=TRUE` (or other +ve number) ?

Comment: @user20650 I think the trace option shows iteration only when there is no error.

Comment: You can use trace to see the final parameter estimate of a non-converged run, or before some errors in estimation. Using the example from the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456634/optim-function-error-in-parameter-estimation) you can see the final parameter estimates before the error. Try `optim(c(5,5,1),gbetloglik,lower=c(0.01,0.01,0.1),method="L-BFGS-B")` and then `optim(c(5,5,1),gbetloglik,lower=c(0.01,0.01,0.1),method="L-BFGS-B", control = list(trace=TRUE))`. Can you try to create some examples (or take from previous SO questions) to more accurately show your issues.